# Other form of nested templates in C++

Tags: c++, class, templates, constructor

I have a class template declaration:

```
template<class T>
class MyClass
{
private:
    std::vector<T> m_data;

public:

    MyClass();

    template<typename U>
    MyClass(const U& input);

};
```

I want a template constructor function to take an input of datatype U. In my ctor function implementations I have:

```
template <class T>
MyClass<T>::MyClass()
{
}

template <class T>
template <typename U>
MyClass<T>::MyClass(const U& input)
{
   // do stuff
}
```

This seems to compile and work okay, but I just wondered if this is normal practice? Haven't come across this in other codes before...

Comment: Yep, this is how it is done.  One `template <...>` for the class as it is a template and another `template <...>` for the function since that is also a template.